# Show initial view every time the app launches

Tags: ios, ios5, uiapplicationdelegate

For security reasons I need the user to log in each time my app is opened.  What I would like to do is when the app is about to close reset it to the initial view.  I know from a view controller I can use the following code:

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

I'm not sure how to adapt that to work from the app delegate.

On the initial view I have it set to show the login modal on viewDidLoad.  That seems to only fire the first time, and not in the app when using the back button, so I'm hoping I'm safe using this method to show the login screen.

For clarification, I understand I will do this in the app delegate, I'm looking for the specific bit of code I can use to tell the app to reset the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution to this could be to stop your app from running in the background. This would completely shut down your app when the user closes it.

I believe to do this you just go to info.plist of your project and check "Application does not run in background" to YES.

Good luck! Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this might be my best bet, but in iOS 5 I don't see an info.plist, do i just add one or is it hidden?

Comment: Its in Xcode in the 'Supporting files' folder and its usually named ProjectName-Info.plist. Also you may have to add the "Application does not run in background" - to do that click on a random entry and you will see a little  '+' and '-' sign, if you click the plus sign it lets you add a new entry.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate.m you can utilise the following delegate method:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive: (UIApplication*)application
```

Take a look through the other `UIApplicationDelegate` methods here, and find out which one will be the best fit for your app:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

---

EDIT:

One way that I accomplish this is to use the delegate method `-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` to display your login interface, is not already done elsewhere.

This method will always be called when the user opens the app from scratch, or if resuming from the background, or if on iOS5 for example, if they're in your app and they interact with the draggable status bar and then close it again, this method will be hit. I think this is probably the best time to ask them to login.

I'm not sure if you want a user to be able to resume on the screen they were on, so you need to decide whether to log them out when the app enters the background. (see the application delegate class reference again, or check out your app delegate method file)

Comment: See my clarification above, I know I do it there, I'm looking for how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately they can't start from where they left off, they'll always start from the initial view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up to display certain views in your `AppDelegate`.

Look at `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Comment: See my clarification above, I know I do it there, I'm looking for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```